# How to create LDAP bind account in Centos/RedHat that allows me to search by ldapbind@server.com

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am creating an LDAP directory and searching by the full DN shows the proper results.

```
$ ldapsearch -x -D "cn=ldapbind,dc=server,dc=com" -w bind
```

I want / **need** to be able to search using the email address as in:

```
$ ldapsearch -x -D ldapbind@server.com -w bind
ldap_bind: Invalid DN syntax (34)
    additional info: invalid DN
```

We have an Active Directory that allows `ldapsearch` to do that kind of search but I don't know what configuration changes do I need in order to have that in LDAP.

I am not attaching my slapd.conf because I want someone to show me the right configuration to do this, and mine is quite minimal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532347/active-directory-to-ldif-openldap

Answer (score 1):

Email field for bind DN works in version `ldapsearch 2.4.23`

Comment: The problem is not that ldapsearch doesn't have the ability to search a DN with email field, the problem is that when I query my current LDAP configuration it says 'Invalid DN'. Meaning the problem is with my LDAP configuration. So I want to know how to configure my LDAP to allow that.

Comment: please rephrase your question properly.

Comment: edit: made it clear that I have an AD that allows my ldapsearch client to query using email. But it fails when querying the local LDAP.

Answer (score 1):

first you may forget to put the double quotes

```
ldapsearch -x -D "ldapbind@server.com" -w bind
```

if that doesn't work, maybe You have no schema defined.

In fact, you should probably just add `core.schema` to your slapd:

```
ldapadd -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/ldap/schema/core.ldif
```

Depending on what you're doing you'll probably also want:

```
- cosine
- inetorgperson
- nis
```

sources:

http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_6&p=ldap&f=1

http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-software/200702/msg00103.html